# iphonesdk printing Document

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

i wanted to print a view(which contain details of payments) from a printer how can i do this? in my iphone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AirPrint.  Here is a pretty good tutorial.  http://iphoneappcode.blogspot.com/2011/05/airprint-in-iphone-sdk.html.
You can also just google "AirPrint Tutorial iPhone SDK"

Comment: this is for airPrint. I want to get a print of pdf using HP printer